# Use localstorage to remember dark mode preference

Tags: javascript, local-storage, darkmode

I'm working on a website for myself, a search engine. My intention is to make it a nice and fast search engine. Now I like the website and have added dark mode. You can turn it on and off with the green button. Now I am a total novice in javascript and I know literally nothing about it. How can I make localstorage remember whether you have turned on light or dark theme?

This is the project: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/mozobrowser?path=index.html%3A1%3A0
and this is the website: https://mozobrowser.glitch.me/

I would really appreciate if someone would help me.

Comment: Hi. Questions asking "How to..." are not well recieved on SO. You should show us what you've tried and the exact problems you've encountered while showing the relevant code. No one is going to look through your website/project to do that for you. Good luck.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and see if you can [edit] your question to make it on-topic. You may also find the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428) a good read.

Comment: Sorry im new I will not make this fault again